# How to get SQL Server FOR XML to format float efficiently

Tags: sql-server, for-xml

When I use FOR XML to fetch values of type `float` from my SQL database, it formats them in scientific format, like this:

```
<foo bar="0.00000000e+000"/>
```

I would prefer it to say "0".

How can I persuade it to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) is your friend

```
declare @t table (bar float);    insert @t values (0);
select bar from @t for xml path('foo');

------------------------------------------------
| <foo><bar>0.000000000000000e+000</bar></foo> |


declare @t table (bar float);    insert @t values (0);
select CAST(bar as decimal(10,2)) bar from @t for xml path('foo');

--------------------------------------------
|               <foo><bar>0.00</bar></foo> |


declare @t table (bar float);    insert @t values (0);
select CAST(bar as bigint) bar from @t for xml path('foo');

--------------------------------------------
|                  <foo><bar>0</bar></foo> |
```

Comment: OK, not bad, if I know what my maximum precision usage is.  Any way to get the machine to do the right thing itself?  Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as the "right thing" from a computer's perspective. The values 0, 0.00 and 0.0000e+000 are all the same - it's humans who "like" a particular representation. XML is for information exchange. As long as all parties are happy with the data, the world goes on.

Comment: OP wants to trim remaining zeros which cast to `decimal` puts and does not want to truncate value which cast to `bigint` does so why don't he just `CAST(bar as varchar(50))` directly?

Answer (score 0):

[CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) is your enemy. It can significantly reduce performance. Read [this](http://thomaslarock.com/2012/08/why-datatypes-matter-3-ways-they-can-hurt-performance/).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how this relates to `FOR XML` ?

Comment: It's probably more related to how the database engine uses indexes. I encountered such a performance problem using `FOR XML` which is why I found this answer.

Comment: With respect, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use my function, when need to be compatible with Excel or some other system like SAS uses 12 digits presision, NB! it does ROUND as well

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FormatAbacus( @p FLOAT(53)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(40) 
AS 
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @dec INT = 10 -- may be as parameter in future
   DECLARE @SIGN  AS CHAR(1) = IIF( @p < 0 , '-', NULL);
   IF @p IS NULL RETURN NULL
   IF @p = 0 RETURN '0'
   SET @p = ABS( @p);
   DECLARE @exp      AS INT         = FLOOR(LOG10(@p)) ;
   DECLARE @power    AS FLOAT       = POWER( CONVERT(FLOAT,10.0), @dec - @exp - 1);
   DECLARE @mantis   AS VARCHAR(40) = CONVERT( NUMERIC, ROUND( @p * @power,0));
   DECLARE @ret      AS VARCHAR(40) = CASE
            WHEN 0 > @exp THEN CONCAT( LEFT( '0.00000000000000',1-@exp), @mantis)
            WHEN @exp >= @dec THEN CONCAT( @mantis,LEFT( '000000000000000',@exp-@dec+1))
            WHEN @exp = @dec - 1 THEN @mantis
            ELSE STUFF( @mantis, @exp+2, 0, '.')
         END;
   IF @ret LIKE '%.%' SET @ret = LEFT( @ret, LEN(RTRIM(REPLACE(@ret,'0',' '))))
   IF @ret LIKE '%.' SET @ret = REPLACE(@ret,'.','')
   RETURN CONCAT( @SIGN, @ret)
END
```

Run:

```
SELECT 
      dbo.FormatAbacus(0.001234567890123456)              AS '_0.001234567890123456'
   ,  dbo.FormatAbacus(  0.1234567890123456)              AS '_0.1234567890123456'  
   ,  dbo.FormatAbacus(   1.234567890123456)              AS '_1.234567890123456'   
   ,  dbo.FormatAbacus(   123456.7890123456)              AS '_123456.7890123456'   
   ,  dbo.FormatAbacus(   123456789012.3456)              AS '_123456789012.3456'   
   ,  dbo.FormatAbacus(   12345678901234.56)              AS '_12345678901234.56'   
   ,  dbo.FormatAbacus(   12345678901234560.)             AS '_12345678901234560.'  
   ,  dbo.FormatAbacus(   123456789012345600.)            AS '_123456789012345600.' 
   ,  dbo.FormatAbacus(NULL)                              AS '_NULL'                
   ,  dbo.FormatAbacus(0)                                 AS '_0'                
FOR XML PATH('Abacus_12_digits'),TYPE
```

Produses:

```
<Abacus_12_digits>
  <_0.001234567890123456>0.00123456789012     </_0.001234567890123456>
  <_0.1234567890123456>    0.123456789012     </_0.1234567890123456>
  <_1.234567890123456>      1.23456789012     </_1.234567890123456>
  <_123456.7890123456>      123456.789012     </_123456.7890123456>
  <_123456789012.3456>      123456789012      </_123456789012.3456>
  <_12345678901234.56>      12345678901200    </_12345678901234.56>
  <_12345678901234560.>     12345678901200000 </_12345678901234560.>
  <_123456789012345600.>    123456789012000000</_123456789012345600.>
  <!--                      NULL is missing    -->
  <_0>                      0                 </_0>
</Abacus_12_digits>
```